# how to add multiple attachments to only one ListItem

Tags: development, sharepoint-enterprise

This code creates a new listitem for every attachment but i only want to create 1 listitem and add all attachments to it

```
SPList myEmployeeDocList = web.Lists.TryGetList("Document cv");
if (myEmployeeDocList != null)
{
    SPListItem employeeDocListItem = myEmployeeDocList.Items.Add();
    employeeDocListItem["Title"] = strUserName;

    if (FileUploadDocuments.PostedFile != null && FileUploadDocuments.HasFile)
    {
         Stream fStream = FileUploadDocuments.PostedFile.InputStream;
         byte[] empDocContents = new byte[fStream.Length];
         fStream.Read(empDocContents, 0, (int) fStream.Length);
         fStream.Close();
         fStream.Dispose();
         SPAttachmentCollection empDocAttachment = employeeDocListItem.Attachments;
         string empDocFileName = Path.GetFileName(FileUploadDocuments.FileName);

         empDocAttachment.Add(empDocFileName, empDocContents);
    }

    employeeDocListItem.Update();

    string empDocListUrl = web.Url + "/" + myEmployeeDocList.RootFolder.Url;
    string empDocAttachmentUrl = empDocListUrl + "/attachments/" + employeeDocListItem.ID + "/" +
    FileUploadDocuments.FileName;

//.... cut ....
```

Answer (score 1):

Well just keep calling

```
 employeeDocListItem.Attachments.Add()
```

for all of your attachments, preferably in a loop

```
foreach(var attachment in AllMyAttachments)
{
        var fs = new FileStream(attachment.FullName , FileMode.Open,FileAccess.Read);

        byte[] theData = new byte[fs.Length];

        fs.Read(theData,0,System.Convert.ToInt32(fs.Length));

        fs.Close();

        employeeDocListItem.Attachments.Add(attachment.Name, theData);
}

employeeDocListItem.Update()
```

Comment: please be more specified i dont get it

Comment: I really can't be more specific than this. You need to create a collection containing all of the files you wnat to add as attachments, call that AllMyAttachments and then copy paste the code block above.